# Prototype.js shortcut for getting value of an element?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I didn't use Prototype.js before, when I use jquery, I can get an element value like `$("#inputA").val();`
Is there an equivalent method in prototype like this? I use `$("inputA").getAttribute('value');`, which is very verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`getValue`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/element/getValue) or `$F(element)` construct

Comment: Does prototype has a jquery like wrapper object? what does $F("inputA"); return ?

Comment: "Returns the current value of a form control. A string is returned for most controls; only multiple select boxes return an array of values. The global shortcut for this method is $F()."

Answer (score 5):

`document.getElementById("inputA").value` is like magic: it works in EVERY framework.

Answer (score 0):

`$F('elementId')` is one way.  That's problematic for radio buttons. I haven't used Prototype in a while however so maybe there's something new.

Answer (score 0):

var x = $('inputA').value;